# MySQL is not working in XAMPP 7.3.0-0 "/opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 260: kill: No such process"

Tags: xampp

when it tries to start XAMPP I am getting the following error and then the MySQL stops.

```
ERROR: "/opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 260: kill: No such process"
```

Any help how I can fix this.
thank you.

Answer (score 5):

To solve an "Access Denied" error you can simply run these commands:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start
```

I hope so this will work fine for you.

Comment: run is not found to be a command

Answer (score 3):

In your xampp install directory:

```
cd /opt/lampp/var/mysql
```

There should be an error log file, named after your computer's host name so

```
$ ls *.err
```

should show

```
hostname.err
```

Towards the bottom of that file it will tell you what has gone wrong.

```
$ less hostname.err
```

I had

```
2019-03-05 13:20:49 140172000044864 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace bugzilla/bugs uses space ID:
 124 at filepath: ./bugzilla/bugs.ibd. Cannot open tablespace bugzilla_/bugs which uses space ID: 124 at filepath: ./bugzilla_/bugs.ibd
```

Which was a bugzilla installation that I messed up. I was able to

```
sudo rm -r /opt/lampp/var/mysql/bugzilla_
```

As I did not need that database and then I could do

```
sudo /opt/lampp/xampp startmysql
```

And my server was now running fine.

Comment: Remember that the `sudo rm` will delete a whole database, so make sure you actually want to do that. There maywell be a less destructive fix, if it's a corrupt database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error [(1. problem with mysql)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCkUT.png) while entering this address ( http://localhost/phpmyadmin ) in the browser then follow below steps [(2. solution of the above error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTtlD.png). After that run it(http://localhost/phpmyadmin) again. I hope your problem will be solved.